# Why are the client side files referred to as static and the server side not?

Tags: javascript, server, client, static-files

JavaScript, html, css files, images, videos etc are referred to as static files and  are usually cached on a CDN (please correct me if I'm wrong).

However I can't understand why server side files are not static? They can still be js files if the back-end is using Node JS, or java files or c# etc. Is it because they are handling requests? If that's the case why answering requests is not static?

Thank you very much for the time spend answering this rather silly question!

Comment: This question is confusing. The files are all on the server. What's static or dynamic is the data that's sent to the client. If the request runs a script on the server, the response dynamic. If it's just the contents of a file, it's static.

Comment: You can generate dynamic JS and CSS, but it's not as common.